# Scroll and slide animation messing up in mootools

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I have an fixed icon if i click that icon when scroll==0 it should open the div in a slide manner.If scroll>0 then it should scroll up and open div in a slide manner.But what happening is if scroll>0 both scroll and slide animation are doing at a time so I can see scroll animation but not slide.As im new to mootools and javascript im unable to get exact function to this.

```
if(menu.style.maxHeight=="0px")
{
  if(scroll>0)
  {
  new Fx.Scroll(window).start(window.scrollY,0);
  }
 menu.style.maxHeight="1200px";
 menu2.style.maxHeight="1200px";
}
```

Comment: If you can make a jsFiddle with this, I will help you fix it.